# Second Monitor Not Detected (20.04.1)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I have found myself posting a lot right here, with no response, but this is kinda my last hurrah at Ubuntu, because I really cannot find a way to get this to work.

I use a laptop, with the following specs: Intel i7-7700, Nvidia GTX 1060, 24GB of RAM, and 1 HDMI port.

Whenever I install the latest Nvidia drivers for my laptop, the HDMI port does not send a signal, therefore, no monitor. I have uninstalled Ubuntu, reinstalled, installed Kubuntu, done everything, but I can't find a reason for this to happen.

If **anyone** and I mean ***ANYONE***, can help out, please do. (if it involves the command line, please tell me what the command does)

---

This is what happens when I run `xrander`:

````
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*```
````

Comment: Connect your display, then boot into a live session (Try Ubuntu) from installation media. By process of elimination you can rule out whether your problem is really your Ubuntu installation or if it's something else like a bad port or cable. Since this is a laptop, presumably with "hybrid graphics", you may also need to change a setting or two in your BIOS/firmware.

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar situation with my newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus Vivobook Ryzen 7. The output xrandr gives the same output. I took Nmath's advice to see if the bootable usb recognized the second monitor, and the answer for me was no.

Comment: @CarterD check this solution, let me know if it is helpful. For your intel i7, you would have to go to the intel driver site. Good luck. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284567/cannot-connect-second-monitor-via-hdmi-cable-in-ubuntu-20-04/1284944#1284944

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this issue, think no more! I found that disabling Secure Boot will fix this issue. Your resolution will fix after a restart, and 2 monitors work after disabling. I figured this out whilst trying to install Pop!_OS.

Comment: Respectfully, this was not the case for me. Glad it did for you though!