# Ubuntu 20.04 Second monitor is not working

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, hdmi, monitor, vga

I tried to connect my laptop with the second monitor, however, it displays on the second monitor that No HDMI signal from your device. When I checked the Displays setting, there is no monitor too.
I use ASUS Gaming. This is the configuration of Ubuntu 20.04
[image]

When I checked `xrandr` in the terminal:
[image]

I also updated to the kernel 5.6 but nothing changes
Here is the setting of the software updates, there are no additional drives
[image]

I hope anyone can help me because I need to work on a big screen.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it not 20 minutes ago. I will paste the solution from this question below: [Cannot connect second monitor via HDMI cable in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284567/cannot-connect-second-monitor-via-hdmi-cable-in-ubuntu-20-04)

OK so after a lot of internet scraping and unhelpful solutions, I have gotten it fixed in my case. I am running an AMD 400 series AMD graphics card. What is downloaded automatically in the drivers upon 20.04 installation is not sufficient. Below, I will outline briefly what I did, but since people have different computers with different specs, I can't get too specific without causing future viewers to install the wrong media and mess up their system.

Below is for an AMD system (If you have Intel processor, you will do a similar step, but on the intel driver site). OP YOU HAVE AN i5 SO YOU WILL HAVE TO GO TO THE INTEL DRIVER SITE

1. Go to https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20
2. Select the software that matches your version of ubuntu/RHEL/SLED. For me, version 20.20 for Ubuntu 20.04.
3. Also look at the download instructions. This outlines the documentation that is important to understand what you are doing!

3A. Briefly, you will download a tar.bz file called amdgpu.blahblahblahb.tar.bz

3B. You will extract it.

3C. You will navigate to it.

3D. You will run the amdgpu-install script in the terminal. I just dragged and dropped it into my terminal and hit enter. I did get a problem here where it wouldn't install at first because there was a driver already partially installed (I think this may have been the automatically installed driver that ubuntu gave us upon installation). To hop around this, I added the keyword uninstall (/.amdgpu-install --uninstall), then re-ran the script again (./amdgpu-install)

4. Reboot and it should work. Furthermore, this will fix any Night Light problems that you were having.

Cheers!

Comment: I had this error when trying to run ./amdgpu-install
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-lib (= 20.20-1098277) but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-dkms : Depends: dkms (>= 1.95) but it is not installable
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: amdgpu-lib (= 20.20-1098277) but it is not going to be installed or
                         amdgpu-lib-hwe (= 20.20-1098277) but it is not installable
                Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.100-1098277)
                Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (= 1:2.4.100-1098277)

Comment: You will have to resolve these dependencies. Follow the instructions in this manual here (page 6, then that refers you to page 36): https://drivers.amd.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf